# CSS Div background image extending to border

Tags: html, css, image, border

I was wondering if there is anyway to make the background image in a div expand to the border.

Let's say I have a div with a background and a border. I want to make the background image in the div expand over the border so it kind of looks like there is no border at all(I know there's no point for this but I need to know how to do it for something I'm working on).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what your trying to do? 
because i cant help you if you don't explain in detail maybe  even an image? What your trying to do does not seem hard. Just post an image of what effect you want and I will make it. Posting attempted code is always a good idea in the question.

Comment: @ItsNotAbyss does my code work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this code:

```
#myImage {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: url("image.jpg")
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Post this in your question if its example code that almost works. 
or set this as an correct answer if this answers your question.